# Django Dropdown List Pass Chosen Value to View

Tags: django, history, dropdown

I am creating an app in django that allows me to edit values of the object and track the history of edits.

I would like to do in django as follow:

choose from dropdown list a value and display only objects that were edited on the day which number matches chosen value

e.g.

objects were edited on 01-02-2016, 02-02-2016, 03-02-2016

so dropdown list has got values: 01, 02, 03
I choose 02 and display objects edited on 02.

At the moment so far I know hot to create a list that contain days when objects were edited. I know how to filter objects as well by selected start and end range.

at the moment I set start and end range manualy but I would like to automate it as written above.

any ideas please ?

**VIEWS**

```
class AllRoomsView(ListView):
    template_name = 'prostats/roomsdetail.html'
    queryset = Room.objects.all()

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(AllRoomsView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        # get context
        context['rooms'] = Room.objects.all()
        context['rlog'] = RoomLog.objects.all()

        # get day only
        roomsdates = []
        for r in context['rlog']:
            roomsdates.append(r.update_date.day)

        # get update days values
        roomextracted = []
        for i in roomsdates:
            if i not in roomextracted:
                roomextracted.append(i)

        # get context again
        context['roomextracted'] = roomextracted

        choosestart = '2016-02-02'
        choosend = '2016-02-04'
        context['roomfiltersettime'] = RoomLog.objects.filter(update_date__gt = choosestart,
                                                                  update_date__lte = choosend)

        return context
```

**MODELS**

```
class Room(models.Model):
    room_name = models.CharField(max_length= 10)
    room_value = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)
    flat = models.ForeignKey(Flat)
    created_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add= True)
    created_time = models.TimeField(auto_now_add= True)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Room, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.value_original = self.room_value


    def save(self, **kwargs):
        with transaction.atomic():
            response = super(Room, self).save(**kwargs)
            if self.value_original != self.room_value:
                room_log = RoomLog()
                room_log.room = self
                room_log.room_value = self.value_original
                room_log.save()

            return response

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('room_name',)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.room_name


class RoomLog(models.Model):
    room = models.ForeignKey(Room)
    room_value = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)
    update_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add= True)
    update_time = models.TimeField(auto_now_add= True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s | %s | %s' % (self.room, self.update_date, self.update_time)
```

**EDIT**

I did manage to create dropdown list but do not know how to post it to another view.

So in my main view I have this:

```
context['rlog'] = RoomLog.objects.all()
        roomsdates = []
        for r in context['rlog']:
            if r not in roomsdates:
                roomsdates.append(r.update_date)
        # get update days values
        roomextracted = []
        for i in roomsdates:
            if i not in roomextracted:
                roomextracted.append(i)
        context['roomextracted'] = roomextracted
```

this gives me dropdown list. I coded dropdown list in my template like this:

```
<select name="dropdown">
    <option selected="selected" disabled>Dates</option>
    {%  for i in roomextracted %}
    <option value=i>{{ i }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
  </select>
```

I do not know how to POST selected value to another view in which I have GET as below

```
class AllRoomsView(ListView):
    template_name = 'prostats/roomsdetail.html'
    queryset = Room.objects.all()

    def get_context_data(self, request, **kwargs):
        context = super(AllRoomsView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        # not relevant code skipped here 

        answer = request.GET['dropdown']
        choosend = answer
        context['roomfiltersettime'] = RoomLog.objects.filter(update_date__lte = choosend)
```

Comment: What values do you want to automate exactly?

Comment: sorry mate, I thought I explained it clearly. I want to automate is I can choose value from dropdown list as written above and pass it to my view so I can perform vilter on it. At the moment I perform a vilter on the value entered manualy as 'start' and 'end' date.